# I need to add a key in json object present in couchbase. How do I write a query for that?

Tags: json, sql++

I need to write n1ql to update json object present in couchbase. Below is my json object name as "Activity", I need to add "parent":"demog", after "attribute_val": "1098". how do i perform this.

Thanks in advance

```
"cus_activity": {
        "attribute_nm": "cO",
        "attribute_val": "1098",
        "activity_type": "hbg",
        "entity_identifier": "12903"
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE cus_activity AS ca 
SET ca.parent = "demog"
WHERE ......;
```

JSON is key-value pair attribute position in object will not have any meaning.